# Find Position in Broken Clock

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, angle

There is a faulty clock — the minute hand doesn't rotate by the angle $2\pi/3600$ each second but by a different fixed angle. The coordinates of the center of the clock are $(0, 0)$. The length of the minute hand is $h$ units.

One endpoint (the tail) of the minute hand is always located at the clock center(fixed), the other endpoint (the tip) is initially located at the point $(0,h)$. One second later, the tip is at distance of $s$ units above the $x$-axis, i.e. the $y$-coordinate of this endpoint is equal to $s$.

Where will be the minute hand (its $y$-coordinate) after $k$ seconds?

What I did is $h\cos\left[\arccos\left({\dfrac{s}{h}}\right)k\right]$ - but answer graded wrong in yesterday test . I cannot wait for Test Discussion so anyone up for it ?

Comment: As you say "One second later, endpoint is at distance $s$ units above the $x$-axis, i.e. the $y$-coordinate of this endpoint is equal to $d$". How is this possible? I mean if some point is $s$ units above the $x$-axis, so that means it's $y$-coordinate is $s$ only.

Comment: Mistake , sorry mate

Comment: This is from an ongoing contest: https://www.codechef.com/FEB18/problems/BROCLK

Comment: No no it was in my weekly test . I'm not into coding , I'm in 8th grade

Comment: Your answer is true only for the first quadrant.